# boto3: How to receive output after calling ecs execute_command

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I want to send commands to a ecs/FARGATE container using python/boto3.
I can successfully open a session using [execute_command](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.execute_command).

But how can I get output of the command? And wait until its done?

I find a a lot about the aws cli and the session-manager-plugin. So one way would be to run the aws cli from python. But is there also a way to get the output of the command from native python?

Comment: did you ever find this out? i seems that you need to use ssm (SEssion manager) but i couldnt figure out how to get the output or stablish an interactive terminal.